# python: construct listed dictionaries according to a conditional for listed tuples

Tags: python, list, if-statement, dictionary, for-loop

## This list of tuples:

```
items = [('Value1','Value2','Value3'),('Value4','Value5','Value6'),('Value7','Value8','Value9')]
```

and I have made a "for" loop to make them listed dictionaries:

```
final_list = []

for string1, string2, string3 in items:

    item_data = ({'key1': string1, 'key2': string2, 'key3': string3})
    final_list.append(item_data)

print final_list
```

### and result is this:

```
[{'key1': Value1, 'key2': Value2, 'key3': Value3},{'key1': Value4, 'key2': Value5, 'key3': Value6}...]
```

What I am trying to achieve is insert another key-value pair according to a conditional for the key1,value1(string1) pair.

I placed this conditional inside the for loop above:

```
if 'Value1' or 'Value4' in string1:
    string4 = 'somevalue1'
elif 'Value7' or 'Value8' in string1:
    string4 = 'somevalue2'
else:
    string4 = ''
```

then construsted dictionary as below:

```
item_data = ({'key1': string1, 'key2': string2, 'key3': string3, 'key4': string4})
```

but I didn't get what I expected and instead it got this:

```
[{'key1': Value1, 'key2': Value2, 'key3': Value3, 'key4': 'somevalue1'},{'key1': Value4, 'key2': Value5, 'key3': Value6, 'key4': 'somevalue1'}...]
```

I was expecting key4's value to be filled according to the value of key1(string1) and with the above statements but doesn't check the next item. It persists with 'somevalue1'.

Comment: Please show us the *actual* code you're running. Not one earlier piece, and then a separate piece of code, and letting the readers glue the pieces together.

Comment: Also, show the *actual* output you're getting: your dict values are not strings, but the tuple values are.

Comment: I was trying to put something generic instead specific according to stackoverflow rules. It was easier for me to write actual code.

Comment: Because actual code shows the actual problem. See the answer below on why you need to show the code *you* are running, not generic code: the "generic" code does work.

Comment: Ok, I just edited the code above because the actual one has or operators as well. Maybe that's what causing the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put all your pieces together and then everything worked

```
items = [('Value1','Value2','Value3'),('Value4','Value5','Value6'),('Value7','Value8','Value9')]
final_list = []

for string1, string2, string3 in items:
    if 'Value1' in string1:
        string4 = 'somevalue1'
    elif 'Value2' in string1:
        string4 = 'somevalue2'
    else:
        string4 = ''
    item_data = ({'key1': string1, 'key2': string2, 'key3': string3, 'key4': string4})
    final_list.append(item_data)

print final_list
```

Output:

```
[{'key4': 'somevalue1', 'key1': 'Value1', 'key2': 'Value2', 'key3': 'Value3'}, {'key4': '', 'key1': 'Value4', 'key2': 'Value5', 'key3': 'Value6'}, {'key4': '', 'key1': 'Value7', 'key2': 'Value8', 'key3': 'Value9'}]
```

**UPDATE(Since you've updated question)**

The problem with conditions

Because `if 'Value1' or 'Value4' in string1:` is equal to `if ('Value1') or ('Value4' in string1):` And this will always be `True`, because only empty string will be `False`

And so to make your code work, change condition block:

```
if string1 in ('Value1', 'Value4'):
    string4 = 'somevalue1'
elif string1 in ('Value7', 'Value8'):
    string4 = 'somevalue2'
else:
    string4 = ''
```

Comment: I wonder why it doesn't for me. I can pastebin the actual code if so required.

Comment: @Twilight0 sure it's required. But you can look at my code and try it, it's collected from your code snipped, so you can just use it.

Comment: Your code works, Snippet even worked for me before I even raised question here at SOF. Actual code has something that prevents expected results.

Comment: Right, I used a different approach for my snippet. Thank you for helping me.